# How to output this array in php

Tags: php, arrays

How I can format this PHP array:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => SUB2:B
    [1] => SUB2:F
    [2] => SUB2:G
    [3] => SUB3:C
    [4] => SUB3:D
    [5] => SUB3:E
    [6] => SUB3:H
    [7] => SUB3:I
)
```

To loook like:

```
<p>Example SUB3</p>
<select>
    <option>c</option><option>d</option><option>e</option><option>h</option><option>i</option>
</select>
<p>Example SUB2</p>
<select>
    <option>b</option><option>f</option><option>g</option>
</select>
```

There are a lot of data like this, where key:value.

Comment: Restructure your array to a multidimensional one. make `SUB2` and `SUB3` keys and make the value an array with the values accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: I'm stuck in sorting it in multidimensional. With right form of array I could make it, this is somewhat messy for my knowledge with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$testData = [
    'SUB2:B',
    'SUB2:F',
    'SUB2:G',
    'SUB3:C',
    'SUB3:D',
    'SUB3:E',
    'SUB3:H',
    'SUB3:I',
];

// reformat the test data and create a key/values array
$keyValue = [];
foreach ($testData as $case) {
    [$key, $value] = explode(':', $case);

    if (!isset($keyValue[$key])) {
        $keyValue[$key] = [];
    }

    $keyValue[$key][] = $value;
}

// print_r($keyValue);
/*
Array
(
    [SUB2] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
            [1] => F
            [2] => G
        )

    [SUB3] => Array
        (
            [0] => C
            [1] => D
            [2] => E
            [3] => H
            [4] => I
        )

)
 */

// now create the <select>
foreach ($keyValue as $key => $values) {
    echo '<p>Example '.$key.'</p>';
    echo '<select>';
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        echo '<option>'.$value.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanx for that. It was very fast and good solution.